# saving position of div after reload not working on first attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this short piece of code to save position of scroll (offset) inside a div so that after reload i will be able to load the page with the div in the same position:

```
   $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
       var scrollToPos = jQuery('.active').position().top;
       localStorage.setItem("scrollToPos", scrollToPos);
   });
```

the `active` class being added dynamically after a click in page but the problem is that after first reload i always get that `scrollToPos = 0` and only from this point the correct position saved...any idea why is that? thx

**UPDATE**:

ok i'll share the entire picture cause i think its hiding somewhere out there. 
i have this dropdown :

```
<ul id="sites" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
     <li><a href="#site_site1.com" class="sitePick">site1.com</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#site_site2.com" class="sitePick">site2.com</a></li>
     <li><a href="#site_site3.com" class="sitePick">site2.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

that when clicked call this function :

```
   $('.sitePick').click(function(event){
     $('.wrapperSite').css("display", "none");
     var site = event.target.hash.replace(/\./, "\\.");
     var offset = $(this).offset();
     $(site).show();
     initPlacements(site);
  });
```

which shows the div of the relevant chosen site. than the second dropdown which is a result of the first one is being created like this:

```
  function initPlacements(site){
     $('#placemetnsList').remove(); // clean previous
     var placements = ['<ul id="placemetnsList" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">'];
     $(site).find('.placementName').each(function(){
       placement = $.trim(this.innerHTML);
       placements += '<li><a href="' + site.replace(/\\/g, '') + '" class="toPlacement" onclick="scrollToPlacement(\'' + placement +'\')">' + placement + '</a></li>';
     });
     placements += '</ul>';
     $(placements).appendTo('#placementsNav');
   }
```

when any of the elements in the second dropdown clicked than this function is called:

```
function scrollToPlacement(placementName){
  $("#wrapper").scrollTo($(".active>.placementWrapper>.placementName[title='" + placementName + "']"));
  }
```

and i scrol lto the div by the title but than i wanted to use the location so that if someone scroll i will still reload to page to where user scrolled, so i started using the first piece of code form the top of my question. now i added this code to execute the scroll on load:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var site = window.location.hash.replace(/\./, "\\.");
    if (site){
      $(site).show();
      initPlacements(site);
      var pos = localStorage.getItem('scrollToPos')*(-1);
      $("#wrapper").animate({ scrollTop: pos + 110 }, 1);
      }
  });
```

but it only works since the second time i choose a website from the drop-down...first time it always initialized with zero no matter where i scroll to

Comment: Can you show us the code when it loads, how are you getting from localstaorage? Are you sure it's being set correctly?

Comment: Can you tell, please, more about testing of this functionality.